# How to use bcrypt in a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, hash, hash-algorithm

Is it possible to use bcrypt hash function in a ethereum smart contract? Or only keccak is available?

Searching I got to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/37513/68459) question, where the OP apparently assumes it's possible, but there is no confirmation or sample code that indicates such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cryptographic functions available in solidity are the following:

```
keccak256(bytes memory) returns (bytes32)
sha256(bytes memory) returns (bytes32)
ripemd160(bytes memory) returns (bytes20)
```

So, `bcrypt` is not available in Solidity. Mathematical and Cryptographic Functions from [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=cryptographic#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions).

It seems that the OP of the other question is using `bcrypt` function to encrypt/decrypt something stored in a smart cotnract, but not using the function within a smart contract.

Comment: Thanks alberto, is there by anychance a "external" lib that implements it? Something that I could import into the smart contract, but doesn't rely on offchain solution? (Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm still a begginer in solidity/smart contracts)

Comment: @Justcurious One possiblity it is that Ethereum core developers implement the `bcrypt` function in the same way that some cryptographic functions are implemented. In something called precompiled contracts, here you can see them: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/contracts.go#L81. This code is from the Ethereum Go implementation, and you can see address `0x02` is for `sha256hash` and address `0x03` for `ripemd160hash`. This is similar to some type of "external" lib as you said. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Justcurious Just to clarify. What I wrote above is only an alternative, but maybe we won't see in the future. Anyway, I recommend you to read about precompiled contracts and how they work.